# Find utility to look for files not in destination directory tree

Tags: windows, photography, duplicate-files, directories

I have 1000s of duplicate photos in many different directories on many different hard disks. My home server has my primary copy of pictures. I want to consolidate and make sure I'm not missing any pictures; is there a utility out there I can use where I give i two directories - a source and destination, and it will show files in the source which are not present in any subdirectories in the destination?

I run Linux, Windows and OS X but my preference is a graphical tool for Windows or Mac.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! There are command-line tools that run on Solaris, and you need to pay for the license. Interested? :D If not: please [edit] your question and specify what OS the software shall run on, and how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions, whether you need a GUI. Be welcome to take a look at our [quiestion quality guide](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for other improvements; the better you specify your requirements, the better answers can match them. Thanks!

Comment: You need a simple *compare folders* tool and there are already [43 questions about that on the site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=compare+folders+is%3Aq)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but it looks like [Nirsoft SearchMyFiles](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/find_duplicate_files.html) might be what you are looking for.  You can select "Non-Duplicates Search" in the Search Mode dropdown.